# CloudFormation Transform inside FindInMap

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to Transform one of the keys passed to FindInMap. The example I was trying to follow comes from here:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/#basic-usage

```
        - Fn::FindInMap
          - 'Fn::Transform':
               Name: 'String'
               Parameters:
                  InputString: !Ref Env
                  Operation:
                    Replace:
                      Old: "-"
                      New: ""
          - !Ref "AWS::Region"
          - 'AppSubnetIds'
```

I'm getting following error message as the response:

```
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 186, column 28:
              - 'Fn::Transform':
                               ^ (line: 186)
```

Is the problem with my syntax? Or is the generally not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax error. One example how it should be for the `Replace` operation  is given [in the repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/StringFunctions/string_example.yaml#L40-L48). Here is a template that I was able to deploy, it uses `Transform` inside `FindInMap` and creates an S3 bucket with a `test-key:test-value` tag:

```
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Default: env-dev

Mappings:
  envdev:
    us-east-1:
      AppSubnetIds: test-value

Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: test-key
          Value: 
            'Fn::FindInMap':
              - 'Fn::Transform':
                   Name: 'String'
                   Parameters:
                      InputString: !Ref Env
                      Operation: Replace
                      Old: "-"
                      New: ""
              - !Ref "AWS::Region"
              - AppSubnetIds
```